# error: unknown database when using mysql2

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mysql2

I encountered some problems with ***MySQL*** when running `> npm start` indicating that I needed to upgrade it. After searching through the web and coming across a recommendation to use ***"mysql2"***, I encountered a new issue causing `nodemon` to crash. The following errors returned below:

```
  code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
  errno: 1049,
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "Unknown database 'usermanagement_tut'",
  sql: undefined
```

*Project details*

```
"dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
  "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "express-handlebars": "^5.2.0",
  "mysql2": "^2.3.3"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
 }
```

I use a windows machine and I have **MySQL version 8** installed

**Updated:** *file structure*

> server/controllers/userController.js

```
     const mysql = require('mysql2');

// Connection Pool
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  port: process.env.DB_ROOT
});
```

> .env

```
DB_HOST = localhost
DB_NAME = usermanagement_tut
DB_USER = root
DB_PASS = rootpass
DB_ROOT = 3306
```

> ufc-fighters-data.sql

> user-schema.sql

Comment: You're trying to select a database that doesn't exist in your MySQL database server. That has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but i have added more information. Forgive me, this is my first time working with mysql database

Comment: It means you haven't created a database called `usermanagement_tut` in the database server.

Comment: Thank you. I've connected the database with mysql workbench and everything works fine now.